# scp-Host key verification failed-AzureDevOps

Tags: azure-devops, ubuntu-16.04, scp

I want to copy file from Ubuntu 16.04 azuredevops agent to remote linux host (also have azuredevops agent installed).

I copied public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

From terminal, all works fine

```
scp myagent/_work/10/s/docker-compose.yml root@192.168.1.76:/opt
docker-compose.yml                                                      100% 1036     1.0KB/s   00:00
```

I created step in pipeline to execute exactly same command

[image]

But now getting error

```
2020-07-08T08:54:43.5359334Z [command]/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/user/myagent/_work/_temp/3ce8bc1e-7842-4f97-bc35-884893882d3c.sh
2020-07-08T08:54:43.5442624Z Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
2020-07-08T08:54:43.6019929Z Host key verification failed.
2020-07-08T08:54:43.6074975Z 
2020-07-08T08:54:43.6245687Z ##[error]Bash exited with code '255'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Copy Files Over SSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/copy-files-over-ssh?view=azure-devops) task to copy files to remote server.

First you need to create a SSH [service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to connect with with the remote server.

> Go to project settings--> Pipelines-->Service connections-->new service connection-->Select SSH.

Then add **Copy Files Over SSH** task in your pipeline to copy the files to the remote server.

If you want to run script in remote server, you can use [SSH task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/ssh?view=azure-devops).